# What does the output of the function mvrnorm of MASS mean?

Tags: r, simulation

Using the mvrnorm() from the MASS package, now we can simulate realizations of multivariate normal distributions. This function works as follows:

```
library(MASS)

MASS::mvrnorm(
  n = 10, # Number of realizations,
  mu = c(1, 5), # Parameter vector mu,
  Sigma = my_cov_matrix(1, 3, 0.2) # Parameter matrix Sigma
)
```

[image: Output]

What does this output mean? Why are there two columns with ten random variables each?

The task is as follows:

Now, I created a function my_mvrnorm(n, mu_1, mu_2, sigma_1, sigma_2, rho), which simulates realizations of the corresponding multivariate normal distribution depending on mu and the matrix n and stores them in a tibble with the column names X and Y. In addition, this tibble is to contain a third column rho, in which all entries are filled with rho.

This should look like the following then:

[image: Expectation]

But I couldn't write a function yet, because I don't quite understand what the values in table X and Y should be. Can someone help me?

Attempt:

```
my_mvrnorm <- function(n, mu_1, mu_2, sigma_1, sigma_2, rho){

  mu = c(mu_1, mu_2)
  sigma = my_cov_matrix(sigma_1, sigma_2, rho)

  tb <- tibble(
    X = ,
    Y = ,
    rho = rep(rho, n)
  )

  return(tb)
  
}
```

Comment: Does `rnorm(10)` give you "ten random variables"? You seem very confused regarding what a multivariate distribution actually is.

Answer (score 0):

The `n = 10` specification says do 10 samples. The `mu = c(1, 5)` specification says do two means. So, you get a 10 X 2 matrix as the result. If you check, the first column has a mean close to 2, and the second a mean close to 5. Is `my_cov_matrix` defined somewhere else?